# How to change color of the JSON message based on status code with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change the response msg to red when the status code returned is not 200. I tried using this way but it is not working.

```
 if (response.data.statusCode == 200) {
            setLoading(false)
            setMessage(response.data.msg)
        }
        else {
            setLoading(false)
            setMessage(`<p style="color:red">${response.data.msg}</p>`)
        }
```

Instead of returning red, it returned `<p style="color:red">Email is not valid!</p>`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding another state

```
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false)
      ...
        if (response.data.statusCode == 200) {
            setLoading(false)
            setMessage(response.data.msg)
            setIsError(false)
        }
        else {
            setLoading(false)
            setIsError(true)
            setMessage(response.data.msg)
        }
```

then in div that displays the message.

```
 <div style={color: isError ? 'red' : ''}>{message}</div>
```